# "Automatically add new top-level pages" Default

Tags: admin, menus

I'm looking for a way to set the default "Automatically add new top-level pages" to be checked when creating a new menu. I haven't been able to find anything on this - any help you could give me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_create_nav_menu', 'PREFIX_nav_menu_auto_add_by_default' );
function PREFIX_nav_menu_auto_add_by_default( $id ) {
    $options = (array) get_option( 'nav_menu_options' );
    if ( ! isset( $options['auto_add'] ) ) {
        $options['auto_add'] = array();
    }
    $options['auto_add'][] = $id;
    update_option( 'nav_menu_options', $options );
}
```

Comment: Just want to clarify draebb's answer '$id' is the menu id that we want the top level pages to be added to automatically. So if we want to get the menu $menu_obj = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_name ); and then $menu_id = $menu_obj->term_id; // yes, the menu is a taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

When you create menu check there's a check box "Automatically add new top-level pages
" just check it and save

Comment: Hi - this is more to have this option checked by default instead of having to check it off each time (for client work). Little miffed on where this is stored/if we can edit that. Thanks!